# Change in resolution in pdf after save by itextsharp

Tags: png, itext

New to itextsharp. I'm not sure if this is the right forum; this is due to the fact that there are three programs involved in the project I'll describe below: silverlight 4, Amyuni's PDF for Silverlight, and itextsharp 4. Add to that the fact that I'm using code I got in a project off the web to translate the silverlight inkpresenter into an image. This includes and "editableimage" class that calls a png encoder class. As you can see in my rush to get this working I've found many tools, any one of which may be causing my problem (translate that to mean that I am using one or more them incorrectly :-).

I have a feeling it's something in the way I'm using itextsharp to save a pdf though it occurred to me that the pngencoder may have something to do with it. At the very least I can see it doesn't compress the png that it creates.

I have a project where I am loading a pdf from a file to a silverlight inkpresenter using Amyuni's Pdf for silverlight. As proof of concept I brought the first page of a pdf into the inpresenter using Amyuni, created a bitmap using a writeablebitmap, passed that to the editableimage object  and the png encoder mentioned above. The png is then streamed to an httphandler where itextsharp converts it to a pdf. This pdf is saved in a database table. I made sure the rectangle for the pdf had the same dimensions as the bitmap created by the writeable bitmap and editableimage.

I then used Amyuni Pdf for Silverlight to read the pdf saved in the database back to the inkpresenter. For some reason the loaded pdf is bigger than the original page from the pdf file. The font is larger, less of the pdf fits into the same inkpresenter. I'm not sure but it seems like the dimensions of the pdf page saved to the database are larger than they were when they were loaded into the same inkpresenter from the file. I suspect that it's some mistake I'm making when saving the pdf page using itext sharp. I have seen posts here in stackoverflow where other people have experienced the same thing. I've done my best to figure this out by googling but, unfortunately, it's hard to pin the issue down considering all the differnt kinds of software I'm using.

```
  Any advice would be appreciated.
```

Fig000

Comment: The first step if possible is to save versions of the document at *all* steps and eval them side-by-side outside the context of your project. Yes, it sounds like your pixel dimensions are being changed. What little info I found on itextsharp shows that it defaults the margins when you create a new instance. If you are creating a new object without explicit margin parameters, and then setting the generated BMP at 100% size on the page, perhaps some scaling is happening. Maybe draw a 1px border on the edge of your original BMP before re-rendering the PDF and see if it registers properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Amyuni PDF Creator for showing PDF files in Silverlight, you could also use it to generate your PDF files with the png image, at server side.

The code will look like this:

```
PDFCreactiveX pdfdoc = new PDFCreactiveXClass(); 
pdfdoc.CreateObject(ObjectTypeConstants.acObjectTypePicture, "Picture1"); 
pdfdoc.set_ObjectAttribute("Picture1", "FileName", "C:\\mytemppicture.png"); 
pdfdoc.set_ObjectAttribute("Picture1", "Left", 0); 
pdfdoc.set_ObjectAttribute("Picture1", "Top", 0); 
pdfdoc.Save("c:\\mytemppdf.pdf", FileSaveOptionConstants.acFileSaveDefault);
```